Fields defined in interface should be part od mongoose schema, neither less nor more
I have an interface lets say IFirm
export interface IFirm extends Document{
    name : string,
    propriter : string,
    ownBy : string,
}

and now I am defining mongoose schema
const firmSchema = new Schema<IFirm>({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        uniqure : true
    },
    propriter : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
})

Things seems look good at this point but the issue is ownBy field is missing in schema and typescript does not complain about it.
The ask is : fields define in interface should be part of schema, neither less nor more
